# TableView with Component Cells

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I would like to use a TableView to display arbitrary `Labels` (one `Label` per cell). The Oracle tutorial refers to a Person class but I would rather not have a backing class, since they are arbitrary columns (each `Label` will perform its own action)

I see that it is possible to make a Map backed table, but the examples I find use String properties, and I need `Labels`.

(Specifically, I need to detect the row and column number when a person mouses over a cell, and display an appropriate value in an associated panel)

Is there any documentation for adding components to a TableView without a backing class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `Label`s as the *data* type for your table. The properties represent the data; the `Label` is a graphical component that is used to display the data. Use a cell value factory to determine the data that should be displayed in each cell, and use a cell factory to create cells to display the data. You can register mouse listeners with the cells you create to update the display in the associated panel.

Here is a complete example you might like to study:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableWithArrayData extends Application {

    final Random rng = new Random();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final int numRows = 100 ;
        final int numCols = 10 ;

        final int numChars = 6 ;

        TableView<String[]> table = new TableView<>();

        ObservableList<String[]> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        table.setItems(data);

        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < numRows; rowIndex++) {
            String[] row = new String[numCols];
            data.add(row);
            for (int colIndex = 0 ; colIndex < numCols; colIndex++) {
                row[colIndex] = randomString(numChars);
            }
        }

        IntegerProperty hoverRow = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        IntegerProperty hoverCol = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

        for (int colIndex = 0 ; colIndex < numCols; colIndex++) {
            TableColumn<String[], String> column = new TableColumn<>("Column "+colIndex);
            final int index = colIndex ;

            column.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellData.getValue()[index]));

            column.setCellFactory(col -> {
                TableCell<String[], String> cell = new TableCell<String[], String>(){
                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (empty) {
                            setText(null);
                        } else {
                            setText(item);
                        }
                    }
                };
                cell.setOnMouseEntered(e -> {
                    hoverCol.set(index);
                    hoverRow.set(cell.getIndex());
                });
                cell.setOnMouseExited(e -> {
                    hoverCol.set(-1);
                    hoverRow.set(-1);
                });

                return cell ;
            });

            table.getColumns().add(column);
        }

        Label label = new Label();
        label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
            if (hoverCol.get() < 0  || hoverRow.get() < 0) {
                return null ;
            } else {
                return String.format("Mouse is in [%d, %d]", hoverCol.get(), hoverRow.get());
            }
        }, hoverCol, hoverRow));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table, null, null, label, null);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private String randomString(int numChars) {
        return IntStream.rangeClosed(0, numChars)
                .mapToObj(i -> {
                    char c = (char) ('a' + rng.nextInt(26));
                    return Character.toString(c);
                })
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this again, it is really important! Why does Oracle documentation not provide a solution for this common use case!

Comment: Probably because it's not actually very common. Usually you are representing real domain objects.